# Doubts in clicking Unordered List in IE using VBA

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I have an unordered list with links in IE and the list is also dynamic. Clicking on the 1st level in the list will open the 2nd level and so on. My work is to select one link within 4th level. So I have to click upto 4th level and click another option after that.

Initially, without clicking anything, the html code of the list will be,

```html
<div class="tree" id="treeDiv" style="width: 288px; border-top-color: transparent; border-top-width: 195px; border-top-style: solid;" ondragstart="return false" onselectstart="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">
  <ul style="width: 915px;">
    <li>
      <a class=" open" id="level1st" onclick="resetTree(0);" href="#">GENERAL </a>
      <ul></ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

After clicking "GENERAL" (1st level), the html code of the list will be,

```html
<div class="tree" id="treeDiv" style="width: 288px; border-top-color: transparent; border-top-width: 195px; border-top-style: solid;" ondragstart="return false" onselectstart="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">
      <ul style="width: 915px;">
        <li>
          <a class=" open" id="level1st" onclick="resetTree(0);" href="#">GENERAL </a>
       <ul>
        <li>
          <a class=" open" id="0/2" style="padding-left: 13px;" href="#">GENERAL </a>
       <ul></ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

To click 1st level, I tried writing two kinds of codes,

```
CODE 1-----
Sub A()

Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim availableLinks As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection
Dim cLinks As MSHTML.HTMLLIElement

Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Navigate 'URL
Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set availableLinks = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("tree").getElementsByTagName("li")
    For Each cLinks in availableLinks
        If cLinks.innerText = "General" Then
            cLinks.click
        End If
    Next cLinks

End Sub

CODE 2-----
Sub B()

Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim availableLinks As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection
Dim cLinks As MSHTML.HTMLLIElement

Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Navigate 'URL
Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set availableLinks = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("tree").getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each cLinks in availableLinks
        If cLinks.ID = "level1st" Then
            cLinks.Focus
            cLinks.FireEvent("onclick")
        End If
    Next cLinks

End Sub
```

Now about my doubts,

1. Assuming my CODE 1 is correct, I am able to select my 1st level thro' innerText 'General'. But my 2nd level also has the same innerText 'General'. So how do I specify in code that it is the 2nd level.
2. Also, in CODE 1, I have used `cLinks.click`. Is it correct or should I use `cLinks.FireEvent("onclick")`?
3. Now in CODE 2, I have declared `cLinks` As `MSHTML.HTMLLIElement`. But I am not using any `<li>` tag in the code. So what should I declare it as, as `MSHTML.HTMLLIElement` or as `MSHTML.HTMLElement`?

Finally, is CODE 1 and CODE 2 correct pertaining to my unordered list? I cannot execute my code and check now as I have to go to my office to do that.

So what do you think? Which one is suitable? I think CODE 2 would be appropriate for all the levels.
If both the codes are wrong, can you suggest a suitable one?

Sorry for the very long post, I am just learning web-scraping so I am full of doubts for which I am not able to find solutions in internet.

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.